# Python Network Logging Example - How To Disable Server Side Console Print

Tags: python-3.x, logging

What is causing the logging output on the server side to print to console in the [Sending and receiving logging events across a network example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network)?  I suspect it has something to do with StreamRequestHandler.

Is there is a way to disable console print without disrupting the logging capabilities on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but while trying to find help on the subject myself I couldn't find much about this.

I have been using a filename with the basicConfig to get rid of the output in terminal:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='{}test.log'.format(logPath), format='%(relativeCreated)5d %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
```

Comment: I'm sorry to point out that this example oversimplifies the problem as one that is solved by calling up basicConfig, but its not that simple.  The issue I'm trying to solve MUST use network logging in a manner similar to the one linked in my question.  I'm not seeing any option to combine what you have provided with the network logging option I'm trying to solve since they're not compatible.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not getting your point since the example you linked uses the basicConfig for the server. It's just not using a filename to show us the loglines directly in console?!?